# How do I echo the name of a file dropped onto a BATCH file into PERL?

Tags: perl, batch-file

I have tried this:

```
ECHO %~nx1 | my_script.pl
```

and my perl script contains the line:

```
open(SRC, <STDIN>) or die ("failed to open $a\n");
```

I'm completely new to Perl so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
my $qfn = <STDIN>;
chomp $qfn;
open(my $fh, '<', $qfn)
   or die ("Can't open \"$qfn\": $!\n");

while (<$fh>) { ... }
```

But it would make more sense to pass the path as an argument.

```
my_script.pl "%~nx1"
```

Then the Perl script can be reduced to

```
while (<>) { ... }
```